# Can't login with Supabase Facebook provider in Expo React-Native app

Tags: expo, supabase

I’m trying to authenticate with Facebook through Supabase, but I’m having trouble. Here is my code on the page with a link to login:

```
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import { Link, Stack } from "expo-router";
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';
import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto'
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';

const ExpoSecureStoreAdapter = {
  getItem: (key) => {
    return SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
  },
  setItem: (key, value) => {
    SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value);
  },
  removeItem: (key) => {
    SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(key);
  },
};

const supabaseUrl = ....
const supabaseAnonKey = ....

export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey, {
  auth: {
    storage: ExpoSecureStoreAdapter,
    autoRefreshToken: true,
    persistSession: true,
    detectSessionInUrl: false,
  },
})

export default function Home() {
  
  async function login() {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
      provider: 'facebook',
    })
    if(data?.url) {
      let result = await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(data.url, Linking.createURL('whiskey-journal://index'))
      console.log(result)
    }
  }

  return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Stack.Screen options={{ title: "Overview" }} />
        <Button title="login with Facebook" onPress={login} />
      </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

When I click the link it opens a web browser and I can login with Facebook, but then it just goes to a page that says “Safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server.” The only option on the page is “Cancel”.

I don’t really understand Deep Linking so I’m sure i’ve set that up incorrectly. I thought I read somewhere in the documentation though that Expo does all the deep linking stuff automatically?

So I’m not sure where I’ve gone wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you added `whiskey-journal://index` as one of the redirect URLs in your Supabase dashboard?